# My observer is always firing when I come back from one fragment to another

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using Navigation Components, I have **Fragment A** and **Fragment B**, from **Fragment A** I send an object to **Fragment B** with safe args and navigate to it.

```
override fun onSelectableItemClick(position:Int,product:Product) {
        val action = StoreFragmentDirections.actionNavigationStoreToOptionsSelectFragment(product,position)
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }
```

Now, after some logic in my **Fragment B** , I want to deliver that data to **Fragment A** again, which I use

```
  btn_add_to_cart.setOnClickListener {button ->     
 findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("optionList",Pair(result,product_position))
                findNavController().popBackStack()
            }
```

Then in **Fragment A**, I catch up this data with

```
findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<Pair<MutableList<ProductOptions>,Int>>("optionList")
            ?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                storeAdapter.updateProductOptions(it.second,it.first)
            })
```

Now, this is working fine, but if I go from **Fragment A** to **Fragment B** and press the back button, the observer above fires again duplicating my current data, is there a way to just fire this observer when I only press the `btn_add_to_cart` button from **Fragment B** ?

Comment: Use the single event to resolve your issue, you can refer: https://proandroiddev.com/livedata-with-single-events-2395dea972a8

Answer (score 5):

You use this extenstion:

```
fun <T> Fragment.getResult(key: String = "key") =
    findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<T>(key)


fun <T> Fragment.getResultLiveData(key: String = "key"): MutableLiveData<T>? {

    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
        if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY) {
            findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.remove<T>(key)
        }
    })

    return findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<T>(key)
}

fun <T> Fragment.setResult(key: String = "key", result: T) {
    findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(key, result)
}
```

Example:

FragmentA -> FragmentB

Fragment B need to set the result of the TestModel.class

ResultTestModel.class

```
data class ResultTestModel(val id:String?, val name:String?)
```

Fragment A:

```
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
    // ...

    getNavigationResultLiveData<PassengerFragmentResultNavigationModel>(
           "UNIQUE_KEY")?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { result ->
           Log.i("-->","${result.id} and ${result.name}")
    }

    //...
}
```

Fragment B: set data and call popBackStack.

```
ResultTestModel(id = "xyz", name = "Rasoul")
setNavigationResult(key = "UNIQUE_KEY", result = resultNavigation)
findNavController().popBackStack()
```

Answer (score 3):

Facing same issue

> Resolve this by removing old data from `savedStateHandle` live data

Inside Fragment B :

```
      button?.setOnClickListener {

        findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(key, data)
        findNavController().popBackStack()

     }
```

Inside Fragment A:

> Here is key to remove the old data by using live data **remove** method and it should be after view created like in **onViewCreated** method of fragment

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    
        findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<String>(key)?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            result(it)
            findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.remove<String>(key)
        }
        
    }
```

***Update :***

**I have created Extension for this for better usage**

```
   fun <T> Fragment.setBackStackData(key: String, data: T, doBack: Boolean = false) {
        findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(key, data)
        if (doBack)
            findNavController().popBackStack()
    }
    
    fun <T> Fragment.getBackStackData(key: String, singleCall : Boolean= true , result: (T) -> (Unit)) {
        findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<T>(key)
            ?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                result(it)
                //if not removed then when click back without set data it will return previous data
                if(singleCall) findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.remove<T>(key)
            }
    }
```

Calling inside fragment be like

While setting data in fragment B

```
   var user : User = User(data) // Make sure this is parcelable or serializable   
   setBackStackData("key",user,true)
```

While getting data inside fragment A

```
getBackStackData<User>("key",true) { it ->

}
```

Thanks to [This Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62768072/4741746)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your code where your last piece of code is called - where you add an **Observer** to **LiveData**. I am guessing it is inside one of the methods **onResume()** or **onViewStateRestored()** or any other lifecycle callback which is called again whenever you return to **Fragment A** from **Fragment B**. If that is the case, then you are adding a new observer to the **LiveData** and any observer of a LiveData receives an instant update for the current value.

Move that piece of code to one of the callbacks methods which is called only once during the lifecycle of a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66111168/8354145

This answer should help in this case. Use SingleLiveEvent.

Otherwise in these cases, maybe using a shared view model (might be scoped to the nav graph) however you won't need to use `savedStateHandle`.

Answer (score 0):

it happened to me, my model observer firing again when backpressed, even there's no ajax request.
My solution is i set flag isAjax=true whenever ajax request
And in my model observer i put like this

```
Model.getResult().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), apiResult -> {
            hideProgress();
            if(!Model.isAjax){return;}
            Model.isAjax=false;
            if (apiResult == null) {

            }else if (apiResult.getError() != null) {
```

So observer progress will return immediately if there's no ajax request, or we can say observer didnot execute if we back pressed